# C# Algebra use in Unity "solve for X"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, linear-algebra, algebra

Hey ill keep this brief since its a basic question, is there anyway to solve for X using C#

Comment: That equation always has one solution: 2. Could you be more precise as to what you are trying to do/solve?

Comment: im just curious if C# has the capabilities to output an answer from -2 + X = 0  

but i assume C# would see X as something other then a place holder for the correct Number to Achieve 0

Comment: As in; solve for X in that equation; just given that string? You may want to look at: http://smartmathlibrary.codeplex.com/ The functionality does not exist in pure .NET

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to do i just couldnt think of the correct way to word it, i apologize for the sloppy wording of the question.

Comment: Thanks for baring with me i think im on the correct path now, if you want to toss in an Answer i can mark it as The correct Answer after i reword the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to solve equations in .NET. Symbolic equation parsing/solving is something for advanced math libraries (heck, it wasn't even in TI calculators until the TI-89).

The following libraries may be of use:

http://smartmathlibrary.codeplex.com/

http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/